# list of current labels in lyx

Tags: floats, lyx, labels

I would like to see all the currently created `labels` in my document in `LyX`. I am creating a `label` and this `label` already exists somewhere in my document. Lyx relabels my item adding a "-1" to it. When I do this again, it adds a "-2". I would like to clean all this up. How do I view and edit all current `labels` in my document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select Document--> Outline, and then *Labels and references* to get  a list of all labels in the left panel. The panel will also give links to the places where each label is referenced, see [Finding cross references in Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131421/finding-cross-references-in-lyx/131453#131453).

- to go to the location of a label in the document, just click it in the outline
- to edit a label, right click it in the Outline panel and select Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I do not know LyX, but the packages [`showkeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) and [`refcheck`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) should help you.  Just load them with `\usepackage{showkeys,refcheck}`.

Comment: could you please elaborate and how they would help?

Comment: @Alex: Follow Document > Settings... > LaTeX preamble, and include `\usepackage{showkeys,refcheck}` in the provided text box. Using `showkeys` only might also be what you're after.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer but the one below was more specific to my use case.